# Is flow or logic stored in data can be a good or bad practice?

Tags: database, architecture, computer-science

It's a theory question of architecture I'm trying to figure out.

In my project a have few pages , each page fires an event (or several event) this event can cause few reaction - as normal flow between pages works

I'm working on a theory that i want to create the flow logic between the pages using the idea as unreal engine created the [BluePrints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFXMW_UEDco&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gY35ezlSQn1sWOGfh4C7ewO)  or there is also a virtual library called [Blueprints.NET](https://github.com/RobinKa/netprints)

so in my project it will look something like this:
[image]

the `send` ,`show` are entries to the logic entities and the `onClick`,`onContinue` and so on are the exit events from each flow entity box.

In my architecture I want to store the flow connection between the pages in the database 
a sample for a data table:

```
EntityID   Event       NextEntityID   EntryID   Parameters
=======================================================
Intro      onClick     Login          Show      NULL
Login      onContinue  Autho          Send      {User,Pass}
Login      onCancel    Login          Show      NULL
```

I know some of the disadvantages i can get from storing the logic in the database (like lost data and false data) which can be worked around does disadvantages

one thing is important that i have dozens of projects that acting the same but with different flow. so instead of creating to each project a logic library (in C# or Java or any other language) . I'd create a framework that can work with same terms and `entity boxes` but different flow each time. without any need to compile a logic library to each project

The **Main** question here is would you do the same? Do you think it's a bad practice? - if so why? - Please remember this is a working theory

Answer (score 1):

An Interesting approach to avoid rebuilding the application.

I think the interesting questions are:

- Which Parameters are allowed and can be passed to an Entity? How you ensure the stability of the Entity-Interface?
- How you ensure the possibility to handle complex data types?
- How to handle different software versions of the entities and the configurations?
- Which errors and exceptions can occur? How to react on it?
- Which flow is allowed? (e.g. can the entity „catalog page“ call the „Intro page“?)

In summary you have split the application into the function-logic and the flow-logic. And since the one is in the code and the other in DB or file I think the biggest problem will be the maintenance. On the one hand to ensure, that the flow configuration is correct and on the other hand, that you don't injured the interface between the entities. And the disadvantage is that the errors can be  detected only at runtime.

But maybe for simple applications it could work :)

Comment: interesting approach - we cant be on a simple application because we've encounter few time the clients requested additional flow or replace a flow and each time we compiling the  logic layer on any change.
about your points , we consider all of those points and we've created a fail safe protocols to each one of them